# infinispan unmarshall cache key from DB

Tags: caching, infinispan, spring-cache

We would like to view the keys stored in the infinispan cache.
We have configured JdbcStringBasedCacheStore and the key and value are stored in DB as well.

When we select the keys from cache table , it is in byte[]. Tried using jboss unmarshaler , to get the actual key but its throwing java.io.IOException: Unsupported protocol version 63

If anyone has tried to view the keys stored in infinispan cache , please help. We are using remote hot rod server - so keySet is not supported.

Comment: Looking into the sources, the code uses javax.sql.PrepareStatement.setString(1, lockingKey); - therefore, there should be plain strings. Have you tried to decode it trivially (bytes -> UTF-8 string)?

Comment: And it's always better to specify which version of Infinispan/cache stores are you using. Especially when it's not the newest release.

Comment: Infinispan - 5.1.6 final and jdbcbninarycachestore over Hortrod .They key is not stored as simple byte[].jboss marshalling is used before storing the key in db.

Comment: OK, you should then update the question description as you say you use JdbcStringBasedCacheStore there, not JdbcBinaryCacheStore.